# Edit final digits in every other value

Tags: r

I have a list of times and dates, taken every 2.5 minutes over a 6 month period. However, my values are missing the seconds element which I need. I would like to add the correct seconds to values which are missing them- so in this example, 00:02:00, 00:07:00, 00:12:00, which should be 00:02:30, 00:07:30, 00:12:30. If possible I would like to do this in `df1$datetime` and `df1$time`.

```
        datetime     time       date
2018-03-18 00:00:00 00:00:00 18/03/2018
2018-03-18 00:02:00 00:02:00 18/03/2018
2018-03-18 00:05:00 00:05:00 18/03/2018
2018-03-18 00:07:00 00:07:00 18/03/2018
2018-03-18 00:10:00 00:10:00 18/03/2018
2018-03-18 00:12:00 00:12:00 18/03/2018
```

I have converted `df1$datetime` into POSIXct.

I am not sure how to do this at all in R. Ideally I would like to be able to do this for my entire dataset which runs until 26/6/18.

Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can add `seconds`

```
library(lubridate)
df1$datetime[c(FALSE, TRUE)] <- df1$datetime[c(FALSE, TRUE)] + seconds(30)
df1$time[c(FALSE, TRUE)] <-  format(df1$datetime[c(FALSE, TRUE)], "%H:%M:%S")
df1
#            datetime     time       date
#1 2018-03-18 00:00:00 00:00:00 18/03/2018
#2 2018-03-18 00:02:30 00:02:30 18/03/2018
#3 2018-03-18 00:05:00 00:05:00 18/03/2018
#4 2018-03-18 00:07:30 00:07:30 18/03/2018
#5 2018-03-18 00:10:00 00:10:00 18/03/2018
#6 2018-03-18 00:12:30 00:12:30 18/03/2018
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(datetime = structure(c(1521345600, 1521345720, 
1521345900, 1521346020, 1521346200, 1521346320), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), time = c("00:00:00", "00:02:00", "00:05:00", 
"00:07:00", "00:10:00", "00:12:00"), date = c("18/03/2018", "18/03/2018", 
"18/03/2018", "18/03/2018", "18/03/2018", "18/03/2018")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you! However this will add it to every value in the data frame, but I only wish to add it to every other value, so that the first, third and fifth values remain unchanged. Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: @Fionn  Updatedd the answer

Comment: Thanks! This works great, although it seems to change every time to 04:00:00, 04:02:30 etc when I run it?

Comment: Actually no worries, I think this is from the data you supplied as it is there before running the code. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Fionn  Because you are updating the original column every time